# meanjs routes tests not working

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, meanjs, supertest

I am using the meanjs `0.4.0` branch. And while performing the routes tests it gives the error `timeout of 2000ms exceeded`. The error comes from this code:

```
before(function(done) {
    var app = express.init(mongoose);
    agent = request.agent(app);
    done();
});
```

I think the problem is that the express server is not running. In there master version the code is:

```
var app = require('../../server'),
   agent = request.agent(app);
```

They have exported the `app` object in `server.js` so in route tests it gets the app instance. But in the `0.4.0` branch they have not exported the `app` object. How do I solve this problem

Comment: If you checkout the latest master branch [link](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/commit/21d87e9378e3598b75918c1f250701a71533a172) it passes all tests like a charm ;)

Comment: Thank you. @ErnestConill. Finally this branch is merged